# Customize annotations in vim

Tags: vim

How could I tell VIM to higlight the `@throws` statement in a similar way to `@param` and `@return`?

[image]

Comment: Vim doesn't hilite any `@statements` by default - check what plugins you have loaded, or what's in your `.vim\ftplugin\php.vim` file (and if necessary _add that to the question_).

Comment: Very good point. I am using [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) out of the box so I need to check which plugin does the highlighting. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383)  plugin to determine the syntax group of the `@throws` part.

Then, you can change the default association (say, it's `phpThrows` and it is linked to `Statement`) by putting the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:hi link phpThrows Comment
```